# Disabling Cache in ApolloClient exported from apollo-boost

Tags: javascript, apollo, apollo-client

I want to disable caching or restrict the cache to 24 hours. My ApolloClient runs exclusively on the Server side.

My environment:

- apollo-boost 0.4.3
- graphql 14.1.1
- apollo-link-batch-http - 1.2.12

Right now, that's how I configure my `ApolloClient`.

```
new ApolloClient({
      ssrMode: true,
      cache: new InMemoryCache(),
      link: WithApollo.BatchLink(),
      credentials: 'same-origin',
    });
```

[The closest thing I saw in docs is `FetchOptions`](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/get-started/#configuration-options) ... But it doesn't specify what options i can actually pass to achieve my need for disabling or restricting the cache.

Comment: One of the `fetchPolicy` is `no-cache` there is a `network-only` option (but that will still write to the cache). I am not sure if this is per query though...

Comment: @Intellidroid Are you sure this option is valid for `apollo-boost`? It doesn't work for me and fetchPolicy is not mentioned in this link: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/get-started/#configuration-options

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not possible with Apollo Boost. You need to migrate to [migrate to using Apollo Client](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/advanced/boost-migration/). This will allow you to provide a `defaultOptions` option to your `ApolloClient` constructor as [shown in the docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/apollo-client/#apolloclient):

```
const defaultOptions = {
  watchQuery: {
    fetchPolicy: 'no-cache',
  },
  query: {
    fetchPolicy: 'no-cache',
  },
}
```

The `fetchPolicy` option can actually be set on each individual `query` call or `Query` component -- by providing a `defaultOptions` object, you avoid having to specify `no-cache` as the fetch policy on each individual `Query` component you use. That also means if you're bent on keeping Boost, you could just do this on each of your components. However, the above is how to effectively "turn off" caching for the whole client.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe someone want to know how to disable caching of `apollo-boost` ApolloClient exactly, so let's talk about it.

@Daniel said is truth, we cannot disable the caching when we do `new ApolloClient` of `apollo-boost` directly, but we can set `fetchPolicy` when we send out the request. The code as below:

```
  // create client first
  import ApolloClient from "apollo-boost";
  const client = new ApolloClient({ uri: GRAPHQL_URL })

  // Set the fetchPolicy when we send request
  import { gql } from 'apollo-boost';
  client.query({
    query: gql`
      query someInfo($id: ID!) {
        info(id: $id) {
          id
          name
        }
      }`,
    variables:{id: '123'},
    fetchPolicy: 'no-cache'
  })
```

The valid value for `fetchPolicy` you can find from [there](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-apollo/#optionsfetchpolicy).